# how to control Led screen via ip address (RJ45 Connector)

Tags: c#, led

I am trying to send data in bytes (stream) to show data on large led display, through ip address or you can say through TCP IP !! i have done this before but by using COM port where i have configure baud rate , handshake and etc options !! but this time its RJ45 wire... kindly any idea for sending data on LED screen ?

Here is my small test code to send data on LED !!

```
            try
            {
                int ourPort = 31299;
                TcpClient ourMagicClient = new TcpClient();
                ourMagicClient.Connect("192.168.0.200", ourPort);

                NetworkStream ourStream = ourMagicClient.GetStream();

                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hi screen");


                ourStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);  
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without more information about the specific device you're using... Anyway, what does the code above do? Does it show something on the screen? Does it raise exception? If it does, what does the exception say?

Comment: this code doesn't give any error ... it is basically used to send data on the specific static IP address on which the LED is connected.